# change build script from Ant to Gradle

Tags: eclipse, git, ant, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have my android git repository which originally used ant build script as it is written in Eclipse IDE.I want to move on to gradle build script.Now first approach could be

i)exporting your project to Android Studio 
ii)Replacing all projects with gradle dependencies.
Now the problem is i want to make these changes in same git repository i currently using.But i believe exporting your project to eclipse makes a new copy of the project and does not allow use the same git repository used originally by eclipse.

Any alternate solutions or suggestions,will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. I think you mean that exporting your project to *Android Studio* makes a new copy of the project and does not allow the use of the same git repository you used with Eclipse.

If you understand Git, that fact shouldn't deter you. Even if you create a new project, you can always copy its files to the old project.

Based on what you're proposing to do, I'd start a new branch in the old project, checkout the branch, copy over the new files and directory structure, do all the "git add", "git mv", "git rm", etc. and then commit the new branch. Once you're sure that the new branch is what you want, you can merge it into your "master" or "development" or whatever. Once you move to Android Studio/Gradle, your project is going to look substantially different, so it's really a new version of your software.

I'm assuming that you understand how Gradle works! I love it myself, but you need to make a paradigm shift.